# New iTunes Connect Rejected app

Tags: app-store, itunes

My app rejected by itunes.
I want upload new binary for same version.
But I didn't find it.
I want to binary reject and upload app.
How can I do?
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you first upload your build, it should show up in the "Pre-Release" Section.  If you've verified that it is indeed there, go back to the "versions" link and hit the plus sign next to "Build".  From here, you'll be able to select your pre-released app and submit it for review.